# Take value from SQL server and delete relevant folders

Tags: powershell

Im new to powershell and would like to 
-delete all rows in a sql server DB that have a date older than 10 years
-for every row that is deleted also delete a folder or a hard disk

So for example if I run the query

```
DELETE FROM [RMS].[dbo].[requests] where date_logged < DATEADD(year, -10, GetDate())
```

I then thought I could get the lowest request_id and just delete any folders under that number.

So for example if I delete 10 rows with my delete query and then do a select
It would say that the lowest request_id is 11.

I've started below but I'm not sure how to capture that the oldest request_id is?
The SQL would be this ...

```
SELECT TOP 1 request_id FROM [RMS].[dbo].[requests] order by request_id asc
```

And also how I would delete any folder "less" than that value.

So if `request_id = 11` then I'd need to delete

```
C:\temp\1
C:\temp\2
C:\temp\3
...
C:\temp\10
```

Thanks
P

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=RMS;Integrated Security=SSPI";
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connectionString);
$commandR = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.requests WHERE request_id= 1", $connection);
$commandCount = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select count(*) from requests", $connection);
$connection.Open();
$rowsDeletedR = $commandR.ExecuteNonQuery();
Write-Host "$rowsDeletedR rows deleted";
$rowsCountR = $commandCount.ExecuteScalar();
Write-Host "$rowsCountR rows in requests table";
$connection.Close();
```

Comment: Deleting rows from an SQL table and deleting files from a folder are two different operations. One requires an SMO object for connection while the other uses the physical I/O system.
I would say you should look for connections between them. What I mean to say is if the name of the folder in the I/O path is same as that in one of the columns (eg Name column) hen you could use this criteria to do both the operations simultaneously.

Comment: If the `request_id` is a field in the record containing the directory name, I would SELECT it into a file, then delete dir directory based on the name in the file. After that I would DELETE ... WHERE... Depending on your database, you might be able to wrap these in an all-or-nothing transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task is broad. I intentionally splitted it into smaller pieces. Take a look at this demo and comments.

---

Since `Invoke-SqlCmd` is considered harmful (SQL Injection), I use my own function to invoke SQL

```
function Invoke-Sql(
    $ConnectionString,
    $Query,
    $Parameters
) {
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList $ConnectionString
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand -ArgumentList $Query,$conn
    $conn.Open()
    if ($Parameters) {
      foreach ($arg in $Parameters.GetEnumerator()){
        $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($arg.Key, $arg.Value) | Out-Null;
      }
    }
    $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
    if ($reader.Read()) {
      [string[]]$columns = 0..($reader.FieldCount-1) |
          % { if ($reader.GetName($_)) { $reader.GetName($_) } else { "(no name $_)" } }
      do {
        $obj = @{}
        0..($reader.FieldCount-1) | % { $obj[$columns[$_]] = $reader[$_] }
        [PSCustomObject]$obj
      } while ($reader.Read())
    }
    $reader.Dispose()
    $cmd.Dispose()
    $conn.Dispose()
}
```

You need a database table. Since there is no strict schema in question, I assume following, minimal:

```
$conn = 'Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI'

$createTestTable = @'
CREATE TABLE MyRequests
(
    RequestId int,
    DateLogged datetime
)
'@

Invoke-Sql $conn $createTestTable
```

There is no sample data, I assume folders named 1, 2, 3, .. 7 and matching records in SQL database:

```
1..7 | % {
    Invoke-Sql $conn 'INSERT MyRequests VALUES (@id,@value)' @{id=$_;value=[DateTime]::Now.AddDays(-$_)}
    mkdir $_
}
```

Table should contain following records (dates may differ):

```
RequestId   DateLogged
----------- -----------------------
1           2018-09-23 14:47:49.113
2           2018-09-22 14:47:49.130
3           2018-09-21 14:47:49.137
4           2018-09-20 14:47:49.140
5           2018-09-19 14:47:49.140
6           2018-09-18 14:47:49.143
7           2018-09-17 14:47:49.147
```

Then, final solution:

```
#get deleted id's using OUTPUT clause
$older = Invoke-Sql $conn 'DELETE FROM MyRequests OUTPUT deleted.RequestId WHERE DateLogged<@date' @{date=[DATETime]::Now.AddDays(-4)}

#foreach id in returned set, delete corresponding folder
$older | select -ExpandProperty RequestId | % { rm $_ }
```